# How to seek to nth record of a file on disk which was serialized using a BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, .net

I need to overwrite a particular record in a file of *identical* objects which was previously serialized using **BinaryFormatter**.

How to advance the stream position to say the **n'th** record and then overwrite just that record?

Or, to put it another way, how would I determine the incremental 'Seek' for each object that was serialized.

Comment: Kind of hard to say as it is difficult to know the record size ahead of time.  You might be better off using _protobuf_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to determine the size you must move the seek position by for each record when wanting to move to the n'th record:

Assuming the file **fileName** passed to the **SerializedObjectSize** function below was originally serialized as a file of Target objects with the binary formatter, said function will return the Seek increment needed to randomly access any record within the file on disk / stream.

```
long SerializedObjectSize(string fileName) {

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        var discardObject = (Target)bf.Deserialize(fs);
        return fs.Position;
    }  

}
```

Comment: You might need to check because generally the first time a type is serialised, extra type information is written out thus making the first record larger than the rest.  It may depend on the serialiser and formatter used